# How to place the morethan one pickerviews in view?

Tags: iphone

Hai,In my app i want to place the 4 pickerviews.And i place the one segment control with 3 segments.If we click on first segment then firstpicker will be display.Likewise remaining pickers are display for remaining segments.But,only first picker will be displayed and remaining pickers are not show components and rows.Only display black screen.Please provide any help.Please urgent.

Answer (score 0):

create outlet and make use of hidden property...means if you tap on first segment make first picker as highlighted and similarly for other segments with respective pickers...

do you want to resize ??

---

***Edit: added code from below for formatting purposes***

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView { 
  return ( pickerView == picker1 ? 2 : 3 ); 
} 

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component { NSArray *values = ( pickerView == picker1 ? values1 : values2 ); 
  return [values count]; 
} 

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component { 
  NSArray *values = ( pickerView == picker1 ? values1 : values2 ); 
  return [values objectAtIndex: row]; 
}
```

check like this..

Comment: No.but only first picker will show the number of components and rows.Remaining shows empty.picker delegate  methods execute  first time only when the app launch.

Comment: - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return ( pickerView == picker1 ? 2 : 3 );
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSArray *values = ( pickerView == picker1 ? values1 : values2 );
    return [values count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSArray *values = ( pickerView == picker1 ? values1 : values2 );
    return [values objectAtIndex: row];
}
check like this..

Comment: add delegate for every picker with file owner and so delegates will be called everytime you change

Comment: @Narayanan I edited your answer to add your code to it, in order to make it more readable.

Comment: Hello narayanan sir,Iam a fresher for this mobile app technology.Iam placing the three pickers in view and add delegates to file owner.And use the hidden propertyin viewdidload method,means firstpicker.hidden=yes and another pickers also same.But process was killed after executing the viewdidload method.And picker delegate methods also not executed.Please guide me.Please sir

Answer (score 0):

To again call the delegates, call the following line

```
[pickerview reloadComponent];
```

Comment: Where we call the reloadComponent Method.This ask nsinteger argument.Please guide me because iam a fresher for this mobile technology.